Transpose Hierarchical Table based on leaf nodes with nodes as first column
I have a hierarchical table categories as follows:



id
name
parent_id




1
Accommodation
null


2
Transport
null


3
Utility
1


4
Maintenance
1


5
Private
2


6
Public
2


7
Electricity
3


8
Gas
3


9
Internet
3


10
Garden service
4


11
Repairs
4


12
Car repayment
5


13
....
..



I want to transpose this to show one row for each leaf to be as follows (I know upfront the levels are 3 at max)



leaf_id
leaf_name
parent_id_1
parent_name_1
parent_id_2
parent_name_2




9
internet
3
Utility
1
Accommodation


8
Gas
3
Utility
1
Accommodation


12
Car repayment
5
Private
2
Transport


6
Public
2
Transport
null
null


..
..
..
..
..
..
..



I tried with the following query, but I just could not get it right (for example, couldn't get the parent's name, only id:
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT id, name ,parent_id, level l
  FROM categories
connect by prior parent_id = id
)
PIVOT
(
  max(id)  --pivot clause
  FOR l   --pivot_for_clause
  IN (1 parent_id_1, 2 parent_id_2, 3 parent_id_2)  --pivot_in_clause
)
;


Can the levels be 2 or 1, and if yes, how would you represent them?

@tinazmu, sorry I did not get your question. Could explain?

Are all branches of your hierarchy consisting of exactly  three nodes? GrandParent (Root)->Parent->Children (Leaf). You don't, for example, have a path, like, Other->Other Expenses(leaf), where Other has no parent.. (levels are exactly 3, instead being levels are 3 at max )

@tinazmu, got you, there could be less than 3. It could be 1, or 2, or 3. I added last row in the output as an example for 2

This should work in most RDBMSs (without using specific SQL extensions, or more advanced functions):
With LeafNodes as (
select *
from MyTbl LN
where not exists 
     (select 1
      from MyTbl PL
      where PL.parent_id=LN.id)
)
select  LN.*, P1.*,P2.*
from LeafNodes LN
     left join
     MyTbl P1
     on P1.id=LN.parent_id
     left join
     MyTbl P2
     on P2.id=P1.parent_id


Thank you. It worked for me. I posted another similar question with slight change in the output: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79147054/2153567

In Oracle, you can do it in a single query without any joins using:
SELECT id         AS leaf_id,
       name       AS leaf_name,
       PRIOR id   AS parent_id1,
       PRIOR name AS parent_name1,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 3 THEN CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id) END AS parent_id2,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 3 THEN CONNECT_BY_ROOT(name) END AS parent_name2
FROM   categories
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE categories (id, name, parent_id) AS
SELECT  1, 'Accommodation',  null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Transport',      null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Utility',        1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Maintenance',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Private',        2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'Public',         2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Electricity',    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Gas',            3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Internet',       3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Garden service', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Repairs',        4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Car repayment',  5 FROM DUAL

Outputs:



LEAF_ID
LEAF_NAME
PARENT_ID1
PARENT_NAME1
PARENT_ID2
PARENT_NAME2




7
Electricity
3
Utility
1
Accommodation


8
Gas
3
Utility
1
Accommodation


9
Internet
3
Utility
1
Accommodation


10
Garden service
4
Maintenance
1
Accommodation


11
Repairs
4
Maintenance
1
Accommodation


12
Car repayment
5
Private
2
Transport


6
Public
2
Transport
null
null



fiddle
