Transpose Hierarchical Table based on leaf nodes with roots as first column
This is similar to this one here. The difference is I want to display the roots in the first column (to the left)
I have a hierarchical table categories as follows:



id
name
parent_id




1
Accommodation
null


2
Transport
null


3
Utility
1


4
Maintenance
1


5
Private
2


6
Public
2


7
Electricity
3


8
Gas
3


9
Internet
3


10
Garden service
4


11
Repairs
4


12
Car repayment
5


13
Entertainment
null


14
....
..



I want to transpose this to show one row for each leaf to be as follows (I know upfront the levels are 3 at max), with the roots appearing at the first column:



root_id
root_name
child_id_1
child_name_1
child_id_2
child_name_2




1
Accommodation
3
Utility
9
internet


1
Accommodation
3
Utility
8
Gas


2
Transport
5
Private
12
Car repayment


2
Transport
6
Public
null
null


12
Entertainment
null
null
null
null


..
..
..
..
..
..
..




Similar to your other question; but this time start with identifying the root nodes:
With as (
select *
from MyTbl RN
where RN.parent_id is null
)
select  RN.*, C1.*,C2.*
from RootNodes RN
     left join
     MyTbl C1
     on RN.id=C1.parent_id
     left join
     MyTbl C2
     on C1.id=C2.parent_id


One solution with CASE and LAST_VALUE:
select distinct root_id, root_name,
    last_value(child_id1 ignore nulls) over(partition by root_id order by child_id1 ) as child_id1,
    last_value(child_name1 ignore nulls) over(partition by root_id order by child_id1) as child_name1,
    last_value(child_id2 ignore nulls) over(partition by root_id order by child_id2) as child_id2,
    last_value(child_name2 ignore nulls) over(partition by root_id order by child_id2) as child_name2,
    last_value(child_id3 ignore nulls) over(partition by root_id order by child_id3) as child_id3,
    last_value(child_name3 ignore nulls) over(partition by root_id order by child_id3) as child_name3
from (
    select root_id, root_name,
        case lvl when 1 then id end as child_id1,
        case lvl when 1 then name end as child_name1,
        case lvl when 2 then id end as child_id2,
        case lvl when 2 then name end as child_name2,
        case lvl when 3 then id end as child_id3,
        case lvl when 3 then name end as child_name3
    from (
        select level as lvl, connect_by_root(id) as root_id,
            connect_by_root(name) as root_name,
            d.* 
        from data d
        connect by prior id = parent_id
    )
)
;


In Oracle, you can do in in a single query without any joins or analytic functions:
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id)   AS root_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT(name) AS root_name,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 2 THEN id
       WHEN 3 THEN PRIOR id
       END AS child_id1,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 2 THEN name
       WHEN 3 THEN PRIOR name
       END AS child_name1,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 3 THEN id
       END AS child_id2,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 3 THEN name
       END AS child_name2
FROM   categories
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE categories (id, name, parent_id) AS
SELECT  1, 'Accommodation',  null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Transport',      null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Utility',        1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Maintenance',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Private',        2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'Public',         2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Electricity',    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Gas',            3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Internet',       3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Garden service', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Repairs',        4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Car repayment',  5 FROM DUAL

Outputs:



ROOT_ID
ROOT_NAME
CHILD_ID1
CHILD_NAME1
CHILD_ID2
CHILD_NAME2




1
Accommodation
3
Utility
7
Electricity


1
Accommodation
3
Utility
8
Gas


1
Accommodation
3
Utility
9
Internet


1
Accommodation
4
Maintenance
10
Garden service


1
Accommodation
4
Maintenance
11
Repairs


2
Transport
5
Private
12
Car repayment


2
Transport
6
Public
null
null



fiddle
